# How to get Visual Studio 2019 to format/refactor variable names?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, resharper

Example

```
var Test = "Hello";
```

to

```
var test = "Hello";
```

I looked into Resharper clean code, but I don't see a section for my use case.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to include the Rename refactoring with code clean up in ReSharper.

[ReSharper Raname help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Rename.html)

[Already been asked](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000338910-Cleanup-Code-rename-variables-)